# Less than or equal comparison within a whiledo

Tags: loops, conditionals

I am in the process of cleaning up the code for [Sieve of Eratosthenes in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-tikz/44682#44682), but saw that when I initially did the code, I could not figure out how to do a `<=` comparison within the `\whiledo`, and had resorted to doing a `<` comparison with one more than the desired number.  This feels like a hack to me, and since @StefanKottwitz is considering posting this on another site with `tikz` examples, I'd prefer to not have to resort to such hackery.

### Question:

How do I implement a `<=` comparison within a `\whiledo` such as:

```
\whiledo{\value{MyCounter} <= \MaxValue}{
```

### Notes:

- As much as I would like to, I can't use the `\foreach` from `pgf`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\def\StartValue{5}
\def\MaxValue{10}

\begin{document}
Note that 10 is missing when comparing to MaxValue:

\setcounter{MyCounter}{\StartValue}
\whiledo{\value{MyCounter} < \MaxValue}{
    \theMyCounter
    \stepcounter{MyCounter}
}

\bigskip
\textbf{Hack:} Comparing to MaxValuePlusOne does the job:

\newcounter{MaxValuePlusOne}
\setcounter{MaxValuePlusOne}{\MaxValue}
\stepcounter{MaxValuePlusOne}
%
\setcounter{MyCounter}{\StartValue}
\whiledo{\value{MyCounter} < \value{MaxValuePlusOne}}{
    \theMyCounter
    \stepcounter{MyCounter}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is a LaTeX3 solution allowed?

Comment: `\numexpr\value{MyCounter}-1<\MaxValue`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I think that would be a good to have here as a reference, but I think egreg's solution seems simpler.

Comment: @egreg: As usual, works great. Thanks. You should add that as an answer.

Comment: (<=) is equivalent to (not >) and \not is defined and works with ifthen package.

Comment: Notice that `xifthen` extends the range of allowed tests (and is a recommended substitute of `ifthen` anyway); it has a `\cnttest` that admits `<=` and `>=`. Nevertheless, I'd recommend `etoolbox` or better `expl3` for more complicated tests.

Comment: what about \whiledo{ \value{MyCounter}<\MaxValue \or \value{MyCounter}=\MaxValue } would that work?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? This does not work as expected, since `\or` has a different meaning than expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can define `\newwhiledo` with LaTeX3 macros or use the `\numexpr` trick, take your pick:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newwhiledo}{m m}
  {
   \bool_while_do:nn { \int_compare_p:n {#1} } { #2 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\def\StartValue{5}
\def\MaxValue{10}

\begin{document}
Note that 10 is missing when comparing to MaxValue:

\setcounter{MyCounter}{\StartValue}
\newwhiledo{\value{MyCounter} <= \MaxValue}{
    \theMyCounter
    \stepcounter{MyCounter}
}

\bigskip
\textbf{Hack:} Using \verb|\numexpr|

\setcounter{MyCounter}{\StartValue}
\whiledo{\numexpr\value{MyCounter}-1 < \MaxValue}{
    \theMyCounter
    \stepcounter{MyCounter}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

`<=` is equivalent to `not >`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}    
\newcounter{MyCounter}
\begin{document}
Note that 10 is not missing when comparing to MaxValue:

\def\StartValue{5}
\def\MaxValue{10}

\setcounter{MyCounter}{\StartValue}
\whiledo{\not{\value{MyCounter}>\MaxValue}}{%
    \theMyCounter
    \stepcounter{MyCounter}
}
\end{document}
```