# TikZ animated Equation in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I'm trying to reproduce the example on [creating a Presentation with LaTeX Beamer – Equations and tikz](http://www.wekaleamstudios.co.uk/posts/creating-a-presentation-with-latex-beamer-equations-and-tikz/) and the given code throws the following error

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/na'.

The LaTex code is

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}


\begin{itemize}
\item Overall mean \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s1) {};
\end{itemize}

\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{equation}
y_{ijk} = \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d1) {$\mu$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=red!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d2) {$r_{i}$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=green!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d3) {$c_{j}$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=yellow!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d4) {$t_{k}$}; }
+ \epsilon_{ijk}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item Effect of row $i$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s2) {};
\item Effect of column $j$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s3) {};
\item Effect of treatment $k$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s4) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path[->] (s1) edge [bend left] (d1);
\path[->] (s2) edge [bend right] (d2);
\path[->] (s3) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d3);
\path[->] (s4) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Also my equation is not animated. Any help to fix this error will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you move the `\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]` to be in the preamble, then it compiles:

[image]

### Notes:

- Two compile runs are required, the first to figure out the placement, the second to draw the arrows.
- You should be using the `\tikzset` instead of `\tikzstyle` as per: [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)

### Animation:

- Since you are using the `beamer` class, the `\pause` macro can be used to create the effect of animation across several slides:

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]                  \pause
      \path[->] (s1) edge [bend left] (d1);     \pause
      \path[->] (s2) edge [bend right] (d2);    \pause
      \path[->] (s3) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d3); \pause
      \path[->] (s4) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d4); \pause
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

With this change and two compiles, you should get an 6 page document that I think will do what you are looking for.

[image]

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}


\begin{itemize}
\item Overall mean \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s1) {};
\end{itemize}


\begin{equation}
y_{ijk} = \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d1) {$\mu$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=red!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d2) {$r_{i}$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=green!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d3) {$c_{j}$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=yellow!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d4) {$t_{k}$}; }
+ \epsilon_{ijk}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
\item Effect of row $i$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s2) {};
\item Effect of column $j$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s3) {};
\item Effect of treatment $k$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s4) {};
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path[->] (s1) edge [bend left] (d1);
\path[->] (s2) edge [bend right] (d2);
\path[->] (s3) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d3);
\path[->] (s4) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your help. Using your suggestion there is no error but not still there is no animation. I wonder how to get the animation of arrows. Any idea. Thanks

Comment: @HarishKumar: Maybe I have a faster internet connection. :-)

Comment: @MYaseen208: I don't see anything about animation in the code or the page you linked to.

Comment: Sorry @PeterGrill, my bad! Would you mind to guide me how to animate these arrows. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: I am not an expert in `beamer`, but perhaps the updated solution is what you are looking for.  The only other animation I have experience with is [Sieve of Eratosthenes in tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44673/sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-tikz/44682#44682)

Comment: @HarishKumar: There is a link in the Sieve animation I referenced above to an Answer Martin Scharrer provided using `pdfcrop` and ImageMagick's `convert` which generates a gif.

Comment: In the example the blue footer appears only after the last animation slide. Is there a way to make this appear on every page during the animation?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: Am sure there is, but I don't know enough about `beamer`. Perhaps post a separate question if you don't find that problem already addressed on this site.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Did you have difficulty with getting an animated gif?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Then you should post it to your answer below.  I was just asking in case  you needed help.

Answer (score 14):

This is supposed to be the supplement for @Peter Grill's solution regarding animation. One can use `<1->` thing as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}


\begin{itemize}
\item<2-> Overall mean \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s1) {};
\item<1->[]{%
\begin{equation}
y_{ijk} = \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d1) {$\mu$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=red!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d2) {$r_{i}$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=green!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d3) {$c_{j}$}; }
+ \tikz[baseline]{ \node[fill=yellow!20,anchor=base,rounded corners=2pt]
  (d4) {$t_{k}$}; }
+ \epsilon_{ijk}
\end{equation}}%

\item<3-> Effect of row $i$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s2) {};
\item<4-> Effect of column $j$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s3) {};
\item<5-> Effect of treatment $k$ \tikz[na] \node[coordinate] (s4) {};
\end{itemize}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\path<2->[->] (s1) edge [bend left] (d1);
\path<3->[->] (s2) edge [bend right] (d2);
\path<4->[->] (s3) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d3);
\path<5->[->] (s4) edge [out=0, in=-90] (d4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]