# Adding a shape (square, circle, etc.) to part of a math expression in beamer (tikz and overlay)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-styles, overlays

This might be a trivial question and I saw similar questions but for some reason, I did not manage to resolve it.

Consider this slide

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
y = ax + b
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

We would like to first see the expression and then highlight ax by adding a color-filled square on it.

How can we do it? There's a very close but complicated question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55216/tikz-animated-equation-in-beamer) but I wasn't able to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**
Ups, I forgot on other shapes ... Added now:

With `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> 
{
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.style={%
        draw=red, semithick, inner sep=2pt}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
With circle
\[
y  = \tikzmarknode[circle]{n1}{ax} + b\ ,
\]
ellipse
\[
y  = \tikzmarknode[ellipse]{n1}{ax} + b\ ,
\]
rectangle shape:
\[
y  = \tikzmarknode[rectangle]{n1}{ax} + b\ ,
\]
and rectange wit rounded corners:
\[
y  = \tikzmarknode[rectangle, rounded corners]{n1}{ax} + b
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
For uncovering highlighted elements in equation can be done by use of `\alt` command (from beamer) as suggested @Unknown in his comments, for uncovering of sequence of equations can be used `\onslide` commands as is done in the following MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.style={%
        draw=red, semithick, inner sep=2pt},
        ALT/.style = {opacity=0,text opacity=1},
        }
\newcommand\mystrut[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
With circle
\[
y  = \alt<2>{\tikzmarknode[circle]{n1}{ax}}
            {\tikzmarknode[circle, ALT]{n1}{ax}} + b\, ,
\]
\onslide<3->{
some text followed by next equation which for highlight use ellipse
\[
y  = \mystrut{2.7ex}
     \alt<4>{ax^2 + \tikzmarknode[ellipse]{n1}{bx}}
             {ax^2 + \tikzmarknode[ellipse, ALT]{n1}{ax}} + c\, ,
\]
            }
\onslide<5->{
and test with rectangle shape:
\[
y  = \sum_{a=1}^n
     \alt<6>{\tikzmarknode[rectangle]{n1}{ax}}
             {\tikzmarknode[rectangle, draw=white]{n1}{ax}} + b\, ,
\]
            }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

A case when sequentially are uncovered terms and in the next equation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,
                tikzmark}
\tikzset{every tikzmarknode/.style={%
        draw=red, semithick, inner sep=2pt},
        ALT/.style = {opacity=0,text opacity=1},
        }
\newcommand\mystrut[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{align*}
y  & = \alt<2>{\tikzmarknode[circle]{n1}{a^2x}}
              {\tikzmarknode[circle, ALT]{n1}{a^2x}} + bx + c\, ,    \\
\onslide<3->{
  & = \mystrut{2.7ex}
      \alt<4>{ax^2 + \tikzmarknode[ellipse]{n2}{bx}}
              {ax^2 + \tikzmarknode[ellipse, ALT]{n2}{ax}} + c\, ,   \\
              }
\onslide<5->{
  & = \mystrut{2.7ex}
      \alt<6>{ax^2 + bx + \tikzmarknode[rectangle]{n3}{c}}
              {ax^2 + bx + \tikzmarknode[rectangle, ALT]{n3}{c}}\, ,
              }   
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** for correct positioning of frame contents MWE had to be compiled at least twice.

**Edit:**
Thank to @Andrew Stacey (see his comment below) the MWE now works as expected. As he suggested, in above codes now are changed `\alt<4->{...}` to `\alt<4>{...}` (and the same at `\alt<6 ...`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if I implemented it well but I don't get the sequential appearance. I mean the ax and the circle are there in one slide. We would like to first see the expression, then highlight it with a circle.

Comment: @VultraUiolet Here is one possibility to add this effect: `\alt<2>{\tikzmarknode[circle]{n1}{ax}{\tikzmarknode[circle,draw=white]{n1}{ax}}`. If we do not want the highlighting, we draw the shape white (= background color). You will achieve the same effect if you use two times `\only`.

Comment: @VultraUiolet Another possibility: `\alt<2>{\tikzmarknode[circle]{n1}{ax}{\tikzmarknode[circle, opacity=0,text opacity=1]{n1}{ax}}`

Comment: You ca mske styles overlay-aware, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/86 and also the aobs-beamer package.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, thank you for info. I will check this late evening (after finishing my job in my workshop :-) )

Comment: Description of the `\alt` (= alternative) command from the [beamer manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer): `\alt<2>{On Slide 2}{Not on slide 2.}`. I suggest to use the `\temporal` command: `\temporal<3-4>{Shown on 1, 2}{Shown on 3, 4}{Shown 5, 6, 7, ...}` or simply `\alt<4>` instead of `\alt<4->` inside `\onslide`.

Comment: @Unknown, thank you very much for your comments. I'm aware for all this possibilities, but today unfortunately so far I haven't spare time to write new addendums to answer. So, please be so kind and write own answer with your suggestions. I will upvote it ;-)

Comment: The reason the highlighting from the second line persists is because you have the specification `<4->` on the `\alt` in that second equation.  Change it to `<4>` and the highlighting will only be on a single slide.  Also, I note that you're using `opacity` to get round the jumping issue when lines are drawn or not drawn - neat idea!

Comment: @AndrewStacey Thanks for repeating my suggestion to fix the highlight error, i. e. my last comment. :-) Probably the reference to the highlight error was not clear.

Comment: @Unknown my apologies - I did not read your comment beyond the suggestion to use `\temporal` so missed your correction of the `\alt` command (I have a bad habit of often only skim reading comments).

Comment: @zarko may I suggest editing the attribution of the correction to the `\alt` command?

Comment: @AndrewStacey, of course.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) for that

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
y = 
\tikz\node[draw=red, inner sep=6pt, circle, overlay, shift={(6pt,2pt)}]{};
ax + b
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By changing `inner sep`, you can increase or decrease the diameter. In order to change the shape, replace `circle` with something else, `rectangle` for instance.

[image]

List of shapes can be found in the manual [71.2 Predefined Shapes](https://pgf-tikz.github.io/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf)

Comment: Thank you. I understood pretty much everything except for shift={(6pt,2pt)}. What is that for?

Comment: @VultraUiolet the node also has `overlay` option. It's required to draw the shape on top, without interfering the text (otherwise, node becomes part of the text, you can experiment by removing this option). So with `overlay` you'd want to move the shape so that `ax` becomes inside of it. `(6pt, 2pt)` means that the node is being shifted by `6pt` to the right and `2pt` to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to highlight something with regard to spacing.  This should be considered an extended comment on the solutions above.

To avoid terms jumping around when switching frames then it is necessary to think about how things affect the spacing, in particular with regard to the line width of any highlighting path.

To understand this, it is worth digging deeper into what the inner and outer seps are, and how they interact with the line width.  The boundary of a node is considered to be a rectangle that is `inner sep` out from the natural boundary of the node's contents (both `inner sep` and `outer sep` can be set to different values horizontally and vertically but that's not important so I'll ignore it here).  If the node is drawn, then that is the path that is used (there are adjustments for other shapes, but they all start from the inner rectangle so again, I'll ignore that here).  However, paths are drawn with thickness and this thickness is equally spaced either side of the "perfect" path, so a drawn node has an *apparent* size that is slightly bigger - by half the line width - of its actual size.  The `outer sep` is designed to deal with this as it is added to the parts of a node's setup that might be relevant outside the node (ie anchors).  By default, the `outer sep` is set to half the current line width.  So if the line width is changed for the drawing command then the node's size will change between frames.  There is a further complication in that when TikZ tells TeX how big the drawing is then it uses a different calculation depending on whether the node was drawn or not.  If not drawn then it uses the exact path but if drawn then it enlarges it by half the line width.  So although the `outer sep` may be set correctly, it doesn't have the right effect if the node is not drawn.  It turns out, though, that TikZ is a bit clever and so will set the `outer sep` to `0pt` (rather than half the line width) if the boundary is not drawn.  This can be used to correct the `inner sep` so that the node is always the right size regardless of whether it is drawn or not.

The key question is, therefore: should the equation look like it would if written without any adornment or should space be reserved for the highlighting?

If the adornment is an overlay, then use `tikzmarknode` with no style and add the highlighting afterwards.  The `fit` library can be really useful here.

If the adornment is inline, then add the styling options to the `tikzmarknode` but make sure that all options that affect its size are *always* present (in particular, line width).  So only change the `draw` (or `fill`) command between frames.

The following is an example showing various combinations together with what it looks like with the jumping effect.

```
% Flush left all equations to make width changes more evident
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/646378/86}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{tikz}

% tikzmark for positioning,
% fit for adding adornments to existing nodes
\usetikzlibrary{
  tikzmark,
  fit
}

%\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}

\tikzset{
  % Beamer-aware styles
  only/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
    \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}} 
  },
  temporal/.code args={<#1>#2#3#4}{%
    \temporal<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}{\pgfkeysalso{#4}} % 
  },
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} %
  },
  % Shortcut for the  style
  surround/.style={
    draw=#1,
    rectangle,
    line width=3mm,
    % If draw is none, then TikZ sets the outer x/y seps to 0pt
    % meaning that this increases the inner x/y seps by half the line width
    % If draw is not none then the default outer seps are half the
    % line width so the inner seps are 2mm
    inner xsep=2mm + .5\pgflinewidth - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep},
    inner ysep=2mm + .5\pgflinewidth - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep},
    outer sep=auto
  },
  highlight/.style={
    only=<5>{surround=none},
    % braces needed as there's a comma in the overlay specification
    only={<2,6>{surround=red}}
  },
}

% Alignment marker to make the changes obvious
\NewDocumentCommand\Marker{ O{.3333} }{%
  \tikz[overlay] \draw[line width=.5pt] (0,.5ex) +(0,#1) -- +(0,-#1) +(-.1,#1) -- +(.1,#1) +(-.1,-#1) -- +(.1,-#1);%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1-6>[t] % top-aligned to show vertical jumping
\begin{align*}
y & = ax + b \Marker \\
y &= \tikzmarknode[highlight]{ax-mark}{ax} + b \Marker \\
\end{align*}

\only<1>{Slide 1: no decoration, equations are perfectly aligned}
\only<2>{Slide 2: decoration on the tikzmarknode, adds space so that decoration does not overlap other elements}
\only<3>{Slide 3: as slide 1}
\only<4>{Slide 4: decoration added after, equations are perfectly aligned, decoration may overlap other elements}
\only<5>{Slide 5: no decoration, but outer sep adjusted so that space is reserved for decoration}
\only<6>{Slide 6: as slide 2, showing no jump from slide 5}

% Overlaid highlighting visible on slide 4
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]
\node[fit=(ax-mark),only=<4>{surround=red}] {};
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Here's a flattened version of the above:

[image: Highlighting terms in an equation, showing the various spacing options]

Note: I've assumed that you're wanting to drawn round the term you wish to highlight which is consistent with what the others have gone with.  If you wish to highlight by *filling* then a lot of the issues with spacing adjustments go away as a filled path has no width.  But then that brings additional considerations with whether the filled region should be behind the text or in front of it.  If that is something you want to consider, leave a comment clarifying.

Comment: Great description, thanks. If you repeat the highlighting effect using the version based on `undecorated node with space`, the viewers know at the latest after the 2nd time that the expression with extra space is also framed again in color. So the framing has then no real highlight effect anymore.

Comment: @Unknown Fair point, but I've used very thick lines for effect, it would be more normal to have `ultra thick` or thinner, in which case someone at the back of the hall may not be able to distinguish between with and without spacing.  There's also the suspense as to *when* the term will be highlighted - just knowing that it will be highlighted doesn't tell you when it's going to happen (got to provide _something_ to keep the students awake!).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hf-tikz` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Boadilla}
}

\usepackage[beamer]{hf-tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
y = \tikzmarkin<2->{a}ax\tikzmarkend{a} + b
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]