# Is it possible to create an animated GIF from LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, tkz-collection, gif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting beamer slides to animated images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23727/converting-beamer-slides-to-animated-images)

I wrote a LaTeX beamer presentation with an animated Tkiz figure. Creating PDF files work perfectly, but I would like to include it into a website. So it would be great if I could automatically create an animated gif file. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It is possible, see [Converting beamer slides to animated images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23727/9467). And your question will be closed if the given link is relevant.

Comment: Also see Peter Grill's great answer to [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44682/3235)

Comment: @Forgiver: Thanks. Yes, it is relevant. Can I close this question by myself?

Comment: @moose: Yes. You can close your question whenever there is no answer posted. As a duplicate is useful, it is NOT recommended to close it.