# Scaling the sieve of Eratosthenes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

Consider the following code, taken from Alain Matthes' answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44678/15874).

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgfmath@function@isprime}{%
\newif\ifpgf@unknown
\newif\ifpgf@isaprime    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{isprime}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
\pgf@unknowntrue
\c@pgfmath@counta#1\relax% 
 \ifcase#1\relax 
 % |#1| = 0
 \pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse
 \or
 % |#1| = 1
  \pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse
  \or
 % |#1| = 2
  \pgf@isaprimetrue\pgf@unknownfalse
 \or
 % |#1| = 3
  \pgf@isaprimetrue\pgf@unknownfalse
   \else
 % |#1| > 3
   \ifodd#1\relax 
   \else
    \pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse
   \fi
 \fi  
\ifpgf@unknown
\c@pgfmath@countd=\thr@@ \pgf@isaprimetrue
 \loop
 \c@pgfmath@countb=\c@pgfmath@counta  
 \divide\c@pgfmath@countb by\c@pgfmath@countd
  \ifnum\c@pgfmath@countb>\c@pgfmath@countd \pgf@unknowntrue
  \else\pgf@unknownfalse\fi
    \multiply\c@pgfmath@countb by\c@pgfmath@countd
  \ifnum\c@pgfmath@countb=\c@pgfmath@counta  
   \global\pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse\fi
  \ifpgf@unknown\advance\c@pgfmath@countd by 2\relax% 
 \repeat
\fi
\ifpgf@isaprime
  \def\pgfmathresult{1}%
\else
  \def\pgfmathresult{0}%
\fi
 \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
\endgroup
}}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\scaling{0.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm,scale=\scaling]
 \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
  \foreach \y in {1,...,10}
   {\draw (\x,\y) +(-0.5cm,-0.5cm) rectangle ++(0.5cm,0.5cm);
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nb}{\x*10+\y}
     \ifnum\nb=1
      \def\pgfmathresult{1}
     \else
    \node[minimum size=\scaling cm](last) at (\y-1,\x+1) {\nb};
    \pgfmathisprime{\nb}
    \fi
   \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
    \draw[red](last.north west)--(last.south east)
              (last.north east)--(last.south west);
    \fi}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image: Output.]

**Question**

How do I draw the red lines correct when scaling the picture? If I use

```
\def\scaling{1}
```

everything is okay, but with

```
\def\scaling{0.5}
```

(as in the picture), the lines are not drawn from, and to, the corners of the squares.

P.S. I don't know TikZ at all, so the problem is probably a trivial mistake by me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `transform shape` after the scaling and with the original code (so that the red lines occupy the whole squares):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}    

\makeatletter
\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgfmath@function@isprime}{%
\newif\ifpgf@unknown
\newif\ifpgf@isaprime    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{isprime}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
\pgf@unknowntrue
\c@pgfmath@counta#1\relax% 
 \ifcase#1\relax 
 % |#1| = 0 
 \pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse
 \or
 % |#1| = 1
  \pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse
  \or
% |#1| = 2
  \pgf@isaprimetrue\pgf@unknownfalse
 \or
% |#1| = 3
  \pgf@isaprimetrue\pgf@unknownfalse
   \else
 % |#1| > 3
   \ifodd#1\relax 
   \else
    \pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse
   \fi
 \fi  
\ifpgf@unknown
\c@pgfmath@countd=\thr@@ \pgf@isaprimetrue
 \loop
 \c@pgfmath@countb=\c@pgfmath@counta  
 \divide\c@pgfmath@countb by\c@pgfmath@countd
  \ifnum\c@pgfmath@countb>\c@pgfmath@countd \pgf@unknowntrue
  \else\pgf@unknownfalse\fi
    \multiply\c@pgfmath@countb by\c@pgfmath@countd
  \ifnum\c@pgfmath@countb=\c@pgfmath@counta  
   \global\pgf@isaprimefalse\pgf@unknownfalse\fi
  \ifpgf@unknown\advance\c@pgfmath@countd by 2\relax% 
 \repeat
\fi
\ifpgf@isaprime
  \def\pgfmathresult{1}%
\else
  \def\pgfmathresult{0}%
\fi
 \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
\endgroup
}}{} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\scaling{0.5}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=-1cm,scale=\scaling,transform shape] 
  \foreach \x in {0,...,9}
    \foreach \y in {1,...,10}
    { \draw (\x,\y) +(-.5cm,-.5cm) rectangle ++(.5cm,.5cm);
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nb}{\x*10+\y}
       \ifnum\nb=1 \def\pgfmathresult{1}
       \else
      \node[minimum size= 1cm](last) at (\y-1,\x+1) {\nb} ;  
      \pgfmathisprime{\nb}
      \fi
     \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0 
      \draw[red](last.north west)--(last.south east) 
                (last.north east)--(last.south west);
      \fi}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like the red crosses to start at the corners of the squares (as in the original answer), but make the entire figure scalable.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg please see the last example in my updated answer.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Sorry and shame on me to propose a "no scaling" solution. Generally I always prefer a scaling method but Gonzalo  gives you a good way to repair my mistake but if you need to scale the numbers too, Lay's method is another possibility with  Qrrbrbirlbel's comment.

Comment: @AlainMatthes No worry. `:)` Thanks for the initial code!

Answer (score 4):

The reason this happens is because each number displayed in the grid is displayed via:

```
\node[minimum size=\scaling cm](last) at (\y-1,\x+1) {\nb};
```

and the crosses are displayed via:

```
\draw[red](last.north west)--(last.south east)
          (last.north east)--(last.south west);
```

The first line defines nodes that are at least `\scaling cm` large. If the font is small enough, it makes them exactly `\scaling cm` large. If the font is too big compared to `\scaling cm`, then their size will increase to fit the number.

The next two lines draw a cross between the extremities of these nodes. If the nodes are `\scaling cm` large, they correspond to the grid (which is drawn in another part of the code). If the nodes are larger than `\scaling cm` (because of the size of the font), then the crosses will be too large.

As you can see in your result, it looks like with a 0.5 scaling value, the font size is small enough to fit the grid, so why is there a problem? The reason is that `tikz` enforces a minimum separator between the content of a node (here, the numbers) and its border. This can be circumvented by forcing that separator to `0`:

```
\node[inner sep=0,minimum size=\scaling cm](last) at (\y-1,\x+1) {\nb};
```

The result is slightly different from that of Gonazlo Medina because the font is not scaled:

[image]

You could also scale the font by adding e.g. `\small` after the `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg In addition, you can also use the option `label=center:\nb` in the `\node` and lose the actual node text. This will never re-size the node (outside any width/height and inner separator settings) but the text may overlap/protrude the node’s path.