# Vertical strikethrough

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I'm currently trying to TeX up a Sieve of Eratosthenes example on the integers 2-100. I'm already using the `ulem` and `cancel` packages to give me horizontal and diagonal strikethroughs but I need a vertical strikethrough as well which would go through the same point as the horizontal and diagonal strikethroughs.

It doesn't have to be a general solution so one that works for 2-digit numbers in math-mode will suffice.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\strike}[1]{\text{\sout{$#1$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c}
    & \cancel{2\:} & \strike{3\:} & \cancel{4\:} & \bcancel{5\:} & \strike{\cancel{6\:}} & 7\: & \cancel{8\:} & \strike{9\:} & \xcancel{10}\\
    11 & \strike{\cancel{12}} & 13 & \cancel{14} & \bcancel{\strike{15}} & \cancel{16} & 17 & \strike{\cancel{18}} & 19 & \xcancel{20}\\
    \strike{21} & \cancel{22} & 23 & \strike{\cancel{24}} & \bcancel{25} & \cancel{26} & \strike{27} & \cancel{28} & 29 & \strike{\xcancel{30}}\\
    31 & \cancel{32} & \strike{33} & \cancel{34} & \bcancel{\textcolor{red}{35}} & \strike{\cancel{36}} & 37 & \cancel{38} & \strike{39} & \xcancel{40}\\
    41 & \strike{\cancel{42}} & 43 & \cancel{44} & \bcancel{\strike{45}} & \cancel{46} & 47 & \strike{\cancel{48}} & 49 & \xcancel{50}\\
    \strike{51} & \cancel{52} & 53 & \strike{\cancel{54}} & \bcancel{55} & \cancel{56} & \strike{57} & \cancel{58} & 59 & \strike{\xcancel{60}}\\
    61 & \cancel{62} & \strike{63} & \cancel{64} & \bcancel{65} & \strike{\cancel{66}} & 67 & \cancel{68} & \strike{69} & \xcancel{\textcolor{red}{70}}\\
    71 & \strike{\cancel{72}} & 73 & \cancel{74} & \bcancel{\strike{75}} & \cancel{76} & 77 & \strike{\cancel{78}} & 79 & \xcancel{80}\\
    \strike{81} & \cancel{82} & 83 & \strike{\cancel{84}} & \bcancel{85} & \cancel{86} & \strike{87} & \cancel{88} & 89 & \strike{\xcancel{90}}\\
    91 & \cancel{92} & 93 & \cancel{94} & \bcancel{95} & \strike{\cancel{96}} & 97 & \cancel{98} & \strike{99} & \xcancel{100}\\
\end{array}
\end{document}
```

What I'd like to do is add horizontal strikes to the multiples of 7 now but can't seem to do it nicely. I've tried using something like

```
\newcommand{\hstrike}[1]{\strike{#1}\!\mid}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\hstrike}[1]{| \! \strike{#1}}
```

But it screws up the rest of the formatting and that's not changed if I use `\mkern` instead of `\!`.

Comment: Related: [Sieve of Eratosthenes in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44673/5764)

Comment: I was thinking about using TikZ but concluded that it would get far too cumbersome, as those examples seem to bear out. Especially as I want to do a different orientation of strikethrough for each prime < 10 in order to properly motivate the Sieve of Eratosthenes-Legendre.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Have done so. It's a bit of a mess unfortunately but I think all the salient details are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created `\vstrike{}` and used in on "7" and "93".  I also redefined all your `cancel` routines to make them of uniform rule thickness and length, and going through the same intersection point.

EDITED to demonstrate the Full Monty on "101".

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\def\stacktype{L}
\def\useanchorwidth{T}
%\usepackage{ulem}
\newcommand\xcancel[1]{\bcancel{\cancel{#1}}}
\newcommand\bcancel[1]{\stackon[7pt]{#1}{\rotatebox{-30}{\rule{2.9ex}{1pt}}}}
\newcommand\cancel[1]{\stackon[0pt]{#1}{\rotatebox{30}{\rule{2.9ex}{1pt}}}}
\newcommand\strike[1]{\stackon[3.3pt]{#1}{\rule{2.9ex}{1pt}}}
\newcommand\vstrike[1]{\stackon{#1}{\smash{\rule[-3pt]{1pt}{2.9ex}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c c c c c c c c c c}
    & \cancel{2} & \strike{3} & \cancel{4} & \bcancel{5} & \strike{\cancel{6}} & \vstrike{7}\: & \cancel{8} & \strike{9} & \xcancel{10}\\
    11 & \strike{\cancel{12}} & 13 & \cancel{14} & \bcancel{\strike{15}} & \cancel{16} & 17 & \strike{\cancel{18}} & 19 & \xcancel{20}\\
    \strike{21} & \cancel{22} & 23 & \strike{\cancel{24}} & \bcancel{25} & \cancel{26} & \strike{27} & \cancel{28} & 29 & \strike{\xcancel{30}}\\
    31 & \cancel{32} & \strike{33} & \cancel{34} & \bcancel{\textcolor{red}{35}} & \strike{\cancel{36}} & 37 & \cancel{38} & \strike{39} & \xcancel{40}\\
    41 & \strike{\cancel{42}} & 43 & \cancel{44} & \bcancel{\strike{45}} & \cancel{46} & 47 & \strike{\cancel{48}} & 49 & \xcancel{50}\\
    \strike{51} & \cancel{52} & 53 & \strike{\cancel{54}} & \bcancel{55} & \cancel{56} & \strike{57} & \cancel{58} & 59 & \strike{\xcancel{60}}\\
    61 & \cancel{62} & \strike{63} & \cancel{64} & \bcancel{65} & \strike{\cancel{66}} & 67 & \cancel{68} & \strike{69} & \xcancel{\textcolor{red}{70}}\\
    71 & \strike{\cancel{72}} & 73 & \cancel{74} & \bcancel{\strike{75}} & \cancel{76} & 77 & \strike{\cancel{78}} & 79 & \xcancel{80}\\
    \strike{81} & \cancel{82} & 83 & \strike{\cancel{84}} & \bcancel{85} & \cancel{86} & \strike{87} & \cancel{88} & 89 & \strike{\xcancel{90}}\\
    91 & \cancel{92} & \vstrike{93} & \cancel{94} & \bcancel{95} & \strike{\cancel{96}} & 97 & \cancel{98} & \strike{99} & \xcancel{100}\\
\strike{\vstrike{\xcancel{101}}}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not sitting right for me. I've attached an image of how it's being rendered
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16453478/strikeout.jpg

Comment: @Stijn Did you forget or misspell `\def\stacktype{L}` in the preamble?

Comment: Ah no, but I stupidly put it above \usepackage{stackengine}. Everything's sorted now, thanks!