# How to typeset a prefix tree (aka trie)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I am currently trying to typeset a prefix tree (also called a trie).  I can make a tree just fine with TiKZ, but I find myself unable to make the prefix tree nodes draw acceptably.  I have attached a whiteboard drawing of a prefix tree containing the words "ghost", "green", "tan", "trie", and "trie".  I can't seem to work out how to make TiKZ draw that same tree.  Any help would be gratefully accepted.

[image: The prefix tree I would like to draw in LaTeX, drawn on my whiteboard]

I have tried rectangle split, and that works to divide the node up into an upper and lower part, but how can I subdivide the lower part?  Also, how can I make the arrows in the lower part come explicitly from the letter, and not from the surrounding node?

Comment: If you posted the code you tried, helpers would not have to begin typing `\documentclass{...}` and figuring out your packages and typing the content for you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The real trick here is how to put the outer boxes around the inner nodes.
As you may have already discovered, it's not possible to embed a `\node` inside another `\node`. It is also a really bad idea to embed one `tikzpicture` inside another (which might appear to be another solution to this problem.  Here's a solution that is based on [Mark Everitt's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/9043/mark-s-everitt) answer to this question [tikz: a big box with fixed width containing smaller boxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40234/2693).

It uses the `shapes.multipart` library to split the tree nodes, and  the `fit` library to put outer boxes around the tree nodes.  The `positioning` and `calc` libraries are used to calculate the placement of the outer node text, and the `edge from parent` path, so that although the tree is built on the inner nodes, the branches actually connect at a point that appears to be the edge of the outer nodes.

**Update:** Based on this question: [How to make tikz multipart node parts have uniform size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61848/2693) I've added some code to make all the inner nodes (both split and single) uniform size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds,shapes.multipart,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    sibling distance=2cm,
    level distance=2.5cm,
    split/.style={draw, 
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,draw,inner
        sep=0pt,rectangle split horizontal,minimum size=3ex,text width=3ex,align=center,rectangle split part align=base},
    boxed/.style={draw,minimum size=3ex,inner sep=0pt,align=center},
    edge from parent/.style={draw, 
        edge from parent path={[->,thick]
        (\tikzparentnode)  -- ($(\tikzchildnode.north) + 25*(0pt,1pt)$) }}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.\node[split] (M1) {g\nodepart{two}t}; 
                [.\node[split] (M2) {h\nodepart{two}r}; 
                    [.\node[boxed] (M3) {o};
                        [.\node[boxed] (M4) {s};
                            [.\node[boxed] (M5) {t}; 
                                [.\node[boxed] (E1) {};]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    [.\node[boxed] (M6) {e};
                        [.\node[boxed] (M7) {e};
                            [.\node[boxed] (M8) {n};
                                [.\node[boxed] (E2) {};]
                            ] 
                        ]
                    ]
                ]  
                [.\node[split]  (M9) {a\nodepart{two}r};
                    [.\node[boxed] (M10) {n};
                        [.\node[boxed] (E3) {};]
                    ]
                    [.\node[split] (M11) {e\nodepart{two}i};
                        [.\node[boxed] (M12) {e}; 
                            [.\node[boxed] (E4) {};]
                        ]
                        [.\node[boxed] (M13) {e};
                            [.\node[boxed] (E5) {};]
                        ] 
                    ]
                ]
            ]
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\foreach \x in {1,...,13}{
    \node (A\x)  [above =5pt of M\x] {Middle};
    \node[draw,red,] [fit=(M\x) (A\x) ] {};}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}{
    \node (B\x)  [above =5pt of E\x] {End};
    \node[draw,red,] [fit=(E\x) (B\x) ] {};}
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: But this answer have no squigly arrows! :p
(Upvoted, nice answer)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I like my trees to have sturdy branches.

Comment: This is exactly it!  As you intuited, I had tried putting nodes in nodes, and I had tried to see how to make my own node shape class (is class even the right word?).  Thank you so much for the help!