# How to make tikz multipart node parts have uniform size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

When making boxed nodes in TikZ, a common requirement is that the nodes be of equal size.  Because TikZ automatically adjusts the size of nodes to fit the contents of the node, this is usually done by setting a minimum size for the nodes, and setting the `inner sep` to 0.

How can I do the same thing for the parts of multipart nodes?  As the following example shows, setting a minimum size for a multipart node only sets the height (as described in the manual).  So how do I make each part be the same size as my non-split nodes?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
every node/.style={draw, minimum size=4ex,inner sep=0pt},
split/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,draw,inner sep=0ex,
   rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split part align=base,minimum size=4ex}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {A} ;
\node at (1,0) {a} ; 
\node at (2,0) {X} ;
\node at (3,0) {j} ;
\node at (4,0) {};
\node[split] at (5,0) {}; 
\node[split] at (6,0) {X\nodepart{two}j};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Not quite a duplicate but closely related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54252/minimum-height-in-split-rectangle

Comment: A workaround would be something like `\node (n1) at (0,0) {X}; \node[right=-0.4pt of n1] (n2) {j};` (where `0.4pt` is the line width and `text height/depth` are set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I updated my answer with the idea  from Caramdir's comment. This method is used in  the tutorial "Diagrams as Simple Graphs" of the pgfmanual.

**Update** With `text width=4ex` it's better to use Polgab'method : `align=center` instead of `\hfil ...\hfil`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
every node/.style={draw, minimum size=4ex,inner sep=0pt,textstyle},
split/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,draw,inner sep=0ex,
   rectangle split horizontal,minimum size=4ex},
   textstyle/.style={text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {A} ;
\node at (1,0) {a} ; 
\node at (2,0) {X} ;
\node at (3,0) {j} ;
\node at (4,0) {};
\node[split,text width=4ex] at (6,0) {\nodepart{two}}; 
\node[split,text width=4ex] at (8,0) {\hfil X\hfil\nodepart{two}\hfil r\hfil};
\end{tikzpicture}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the `text width` solution a much cleaner one altogether. And it's simple to make a macro to wrap the part contents in `\hfil`s.  (We can probably delete the clarifying comments.)

Comment: There is a downside of removing the `align=base` part: now if you have e.g. an `X` and an `r` in the two parts they are not aligned with the same baseline.

Comment: You have the same problem with `a`and `A` in the single nodes

Comment: Yes, but in that case it's much less noticeable. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn: To make the letters align properly, add something like `text height=0.9em,text depth=0.5ex` to the options.

Comment: @Caramdir: You are right. But this is not sufficient: part two does not use `text height` and `text depth`! We must add `rectangle split part align=base`.

Comment: @Caramdir Good idea as usual !

Comment: @PolGab: It seems to work in Altermundus example (even with a j in place of the r).

Comment: Without `rectangle split part align=base` the result depends of the values of `text height`and `text depth`. PolGab's method is the better way.

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution with `rectangle split part align=base` (and using `chains` just to chain the nodes).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=going right,node distance=.5ex]
  \tikzset{
    simple node/.style={
      draw,
      text height=2.8ex,text depth=1.2ex,
      inner sep=0pt,text width=4ex,align=center
    },
    split node/.style={
      simple node,
      rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=2,
      draw,inner sep=0ex,rectangle split part align=base,
    },
  }
  \node[on chain,simple node] {j} ;
  \node[on chain,split node] {j\nodepart{two}A};
  \node[on chain,simple node] {A} ; 
  \node[on chain,simple node] {X} ;
  \node[on chain,split node] {X\nodepart{two}j};
  \node[on chain,simple node] {j} ;
  \node[on chain,split node] {.\nodepart{two}\textbullet}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Below the result without `rectangle split part align=base` (note the difference between `j` on left or on right part of slit node):

[image]

Comment: Yes you are right with `text width=4ex` the correct way is to use `align=center`. I find my problem, with `text height=2.8ex,text depth=1.2ex` and `rectangle split part align=base`, there is no problem to align the characters.