# How to draw a slanted rectangle divided by two using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following rectangle divided by two using `tikzpicture` environment:

[image: What I want]

However, what I achieved so far is:

[image: What I have done so far]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

% Bend curves from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/152550
\begin{tikzpicture}[delay rect/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,draw,
minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=1cm, 
text width=2cm,align=center,inner ysep=2cm,draw,inner ysep=3mm,inner
xsep=3mm}]  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452609/152550
    \node (start) at (0,0) {Start};
    \node (end) at (6,0) {End};
    \node[rotate=60,delay rect] (delay) at (3,0) {A1\nodepart{two}text here};
    \def\myshift#1{\scriptsize\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|hello}}}] (start) to [bend left=10] (delay);
    \draw [->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|bye}}}] (delay) to [bend left=10] (end);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to your style definition for `delay rec` you need to add the option `rectangle split horizontal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
% Bend curves from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/152550
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
delay rect/.style = {rectangle split,  % all double and not used options in style are removed
                     rectangle split horizontal,   % <---
                     rectangle split parts=2, draw,
                     minimum height=1cm,
                     align=center,
                     inner ysep=3mm,inner xsep=3mm}
                        ]  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452609/152550
    \node (start) at (0,0) {Start};
    \node (end) at (6,0) {End};
    \node[delay rect,rotate=60] (delay) at (3,0) {A1\nodepart{two}text here};
    \def\myshift#1{\scriptsize\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw [->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|hello}}}] (start) to [bend left=10] (delay);
    \draw [->,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|bye}}}] (delay) to [bend left=10] (end);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

regarding sub questions in your comment below:

1) reduce the font size of the rectangle (\scriptsize)?

```
in node style definition just define font size with `font=\scriptsize`
```

2) reduce a little more the height of the rectangle?

```
in height of a rectangles are defined by `minimum height = <desired height>`. you have selected 1cmm, if this is to much, reduce for example to 7mm
```

3) reduce a little more the width of each part of the rectangle so that there is not so much space between the text and the edges

```
space between node border lines and nodes content (text) is controlled by `inner sep` (equal for all direction) or `inner ysep` in vertical direction) and `inner xsep` for horizontal. default value is `3pt`. if this is to much to you, than to node's style option add for example `inner sep=2pt`.
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! Do you know how can we 1) reduce the font size of the rectangle (`\scriptsize`)?; 2) reduce a little more the height of the rectangle?; 3) reduce a little more the width of each part of the rectangle so that there is not so much space between the text and the edges? (the latter is not necessary)

Comment: @manooooh, i belive that is now time to read `tikz & pgf manual`, at least part  III  :-). i will add some instruction to answer asap (however, this is not part of your question).

Comment: Forget that.... That's perfect, I can solve the font size by using `{\scriptsize A1\nodepart{two}\scriptsize text here}` and adding `minimum height=.1cm`.

Comment: @manooooh, don't doing this. you will destroy baseline distance of text. use approach described in explanation added to answer.