# How to get horizonzal alignment right for nested rectangles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that nesting tikz pictures [is](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture) [considered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40192/tikz-how-to-refer-to-a-node-in-nested-nodes) [bad](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node), but I did it anyway as I don't want to mess around with manual positioning. I'm nesting several rectangles similar to [another question for circles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/nesting-tikzpicture-within-tikzpicture-elements-good-or-bad-practice). The problem is that the rectangles aren't centered correctly, which can be seen at the left and right stacking vertical lines.

[image: nesting]

Is this a problem caused by nesting or am I doing something different wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    class/.style={
      draw,
      align=center,
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=20pt,
      minimum size=0pt,
      inner sep=5pt,
      outer sep=0pt,
    },
    label/.style={
      rectangle,
      align=center,
      inner sep=6pt,
      outer sep=4pt, % shifts labels a bit down
      node distance=0pt,
    },
  ]

  \node [class] (csl) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node [class] (ptime) {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \node [class] (mcfl) {
            \begin{tikzpicture}
              \node [class] (rpl) {
                \begin{tikzpicture}
                  \node [class] (tal) {
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                      \node [class,rounded corners=5pt] (cfl) {CFG};
                      \node [label, below=of cfl] {TAG, LIG, CCG, HG };
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                  };
                  \node [label, below=of tal] {RPG, (2,2)-MCFG};
                \end{tikzpicture}
              };
              \node [label, below=of rpl] {MCFG, LCFRS};
            \end{tikzpicture}
          };
          \node [label, below=of mcfl] {RCG, simple LMG \\ (= PTIME)};
        \end{tikzpicture}
      };
      \node [label, below=of ptime] {CSG};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to read [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html).

Comment: Just add `%` after each `\end{tikzpicture}` or don't put the node ending on the next line (e.g., `\end{tikzpicture}};`).

Comment: @MarkWibrow Oh boy... thank you so much! Please write a quick answer for that :)

Answer (score 1):

Compare the code below with yours. There is still room for improvements.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit}
\tikzset{every fit/.append style=text badly centered}
\tikzset{class/.style={
      draw,
      rectangle,
      rounded corners=20pt,
      inner ysep=5pt,
    },
        label/.style={
      align=center,
      inner sep=6pt,
      outer ysep=4pt,
      node distance=0pt,
    }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node [class,rounded corners=5pt] (cfl) {CFG};
\node [label, below=of cfl] (tal) {TAG, LIG, CCG, HG };
\node [label, below=of tal] (rpl) {RPG, (2,2)-MCFG};
\node [label, below=of rpl] (mcfl) {MCFG, LCFRS};
\node [label, below=of mcfl] (ptime) {RCG, simple LMG \\ (= PTIME)};
\node [label, below=of ptime] (csl) {CSG};

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [class, inner xsep=5em, fit=(cfl) (tal) (rpl) (mcfl) (ptime) (csl)] {};
    \node [class, inner xsep=4em, fit=(cfl) (tal) (rpl) (mcfl) (ptime)] {};
    \node [class, inner xsep=3em, fit=(cfl) (tal) (rpl) (mcfl)] {};
    \node [class, inner xsep=2em, fit=(cfl) (tal) (rpl)] {};
    \node [class, inner xsep=1em, fit=(cfl) (tal)] {};
\end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```