# How can I remove the white space within a cloud in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to produce a figure which contains a cloud drawn around a set of images. The code I have so far is:

```
\node [draw, cloud, cloud puffs=20, aspect=2, inner sep=0cm] (pathways) 
 {\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node at (0,0) [inner sep = 0pt] (pathway) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{png/WP716_74442.png}};
   \node at (2,1) [inner sep = 0pt] (pathway2) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{png/WP716_74442.png}};
   \node at (1,2) [inner sep = 0pt] (pathway3) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{png/WP716_74442.png}};
   \node at (4,2) [inner sep = 0pt] (pathway4) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{png/WP706_74443.png}};
   \node [above left = of pathway2] (pathway5) {\includegraphics[width=4cm]{png/WP1591_73381.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
};
```

This results in the following cloud:

[image: TikZ cloud]

There is to much white space to my liking. I prefer the line of the cloud the just barely touch the figures included. 
According to an [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95655/13715), I should use inner sep=0cm. However the white space surrounding the figures remain.

What I need is a cloud that is drawn around a set of figures in png format. What do I need to do, to get a smaller cloud (with less white space).

Comment: Did you try a negative `inner sep` value?

Comment: @PaulGessler Great that did it. Didn't know you could provide negative values.

Answer (score 8):

The key `inner sep` may have negative values. So you can use this to adjust to your liking the size of the shape relative to the images. But, as noted by percusse in a comment, negative `inner sep` values can lead to nasty overlap and miscalculated bounding boxes that may show up if you have other things in the drawing. Note also that nesting `tikzpicture`s is generally liable to cause problems (c.f. [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51193/nesting-tikzpicture-within-tikzpicture-elements-good-or-bad-practice) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47377/proper-nesting-of-tikzpicture-environments-reset-all-pgf-values-to-their-defaul) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46598/problem-with-overlay-when-a-tikzpicture-is-inside-another-tikzpicture) [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47359/how-to-typeset-a-tikz-picture-inside-a-node) [5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40192/tikz-how-to-refer-to-a-node-in-nested-nodes)), but in this case it works fine.

A better approach would be to use the `fit` library, as I've shown here, which avoids the nested `tikzpicture`s. This also has the benefit of requiring less drastic adjustments to `inner sep`. For example, in this code I was able to use `inner sep=0pt` and I think it fits close enough. As they say in many cookbooks, "season to taste."

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,fit} % added fit library
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw the named nodes
  \node (a) at (0,0) [inner sep = 0pt] {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}};
  \node (b) at (4,1) [inner sep = 0pt] {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}};
  % draw the cloud node, fitted to named nodes (a) and (b)
  \node [draw, inner sep=0pt, cloud, cloud puffs=20, aspect=2,fit=(a) (b)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May take negative values but shouldn't. Try `\tikz{\node[draw] (a) at (0,0) [inner sep = -5pt] {\Huge A}; \draw (a) -- (5mm,0);}`. It leads to miscalculated bounding boxes too.